# Iterm2: hide hostname and git branch

Tags: zsh, iterm2, iterm

I use **iterm2** and **oh-my-zsh**.

`How can i hide hostname and git branch name?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open ~/.zshrc, search keyword `ZSH_THEME=` and find the theme that you are using.
2. open the theme file from `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/` and override the Git and Hostname variables to what you want, you can also modify the color to make the git not showing this shining.
3. save the changes and execute `source ~/.zshrc` to let the modification take into effect.